# Lebesgue-measurability of some union of boxes

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $B_i$ be a family of closed boxes in $R^n$ with interior points. Is $\cup_{i\in I}B_i$ Lebesgue-measurable?

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you're asking please?

Comment: Sorry I use this page for the first time . Please tell me where is unclear point ?

Comment: First thing, is $I$ countable. Second, are those any specific boxes? Things like that. Also, you should include some your efforts about the problem/introduction/explanation of the problem, things like what were you doing to arrive at it. It's to avoid being downvoted and eventually having your question closed. You can treat it like, you respect us then we will respect you as well.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and edition. I is not necessarily countable set. Box is defined as the direct product of intervals. 
I think this is Lebesgue measurable. But I have no idea. The information of interior points is necessary because one point is closed box and there is α non-Lebesgue measurable set in $R^n$. Please help me.

Comment: Do you need that the measure of the union is also finite?

Comment: I know that the union of any family of closed intervals (of positive length) in $\mathbb R$ is Lebesegue measurable. [ Not very easy to prove]. I believe that the answer to your question is YES. But I do not know any reference for this result.

Comment: I think your question is equivalent to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572863/show-that-the-union-over-a-collection-of-compact-cubes-in-mathbbrn-is-lebe), since a box can be written as a finite union of cubes.